# Doctrine entity repository with additional aggregated fields

Tags: doctrine, repository, entity

I have an entity `Client`, with a relation to an entity `Contract`. Contract has got a field `amount` and a field `payingDelay`.

`Client.php`

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Contract", mappedBy="client")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="contract_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $contract;
```

I'd like to show a list of all clients with some basic client fields and also some calculated (SUM, etc.) information on contracts, like this:

```
name - num contracts    - sum(amounts)  - aggregated risk
John - COUNT(contracts) - SUM(C.amount) - SUM(C.amount * C.payingDelay) 

This is my basic `findClientWithCalculations()` method in `ClientRepository`:

        return $this->createQueryBuilder('CLI')
            ->join('CLI.contract', 'CON')
            ->orderBy('CON.startDate', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

Is there a way I can add extra columns to this QueryBuilder, even if the final structure doesn't match the structure of a Client object or this must be done outside from a repository?

If not, maybe I can build a custom query in a controller and pass the query result to a twig template to show this structure.

Thank you.
```

Comment: There are many ways to select what you need using doctrine. Check the documentation for the query builder. You can use the select() function of the query builder to select only the fields you need, including "COUNT(contracts) AS numContracts", in a string. You can also add an array and select entities separately. Basically, whatever works for you. You will need a groupBy('client.id') most likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not trivial, the question is not correctly formulated. I thought that an entitity repository method had to implement always some kind of `findBy()` method and return an object or a collection of objects of that entity to which this repository belongs.

Actually, an entitity repository method can return anything, so this problem can be solved using native query inside the entitity repository method.

For example:

`ClientRepository.php:`

```
public function findWithContractStatus($contractStatusShortname)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $clientQuery = "select distinct CLI.id, CLI.name, COUNT(contracts) as ncontracts, SUM(C.amount) as amount from client CLI join contract CON on CON.client_id = CON.id group by CLI.id, CLI.name"

    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm->addScalarResult('id', 'id');
    $rsm->addScalarResult('name', 'name');
    $rsm->addScalarResult('ncontracts', 'ncontracts');
    $rsm->addScalarResult('amount', 'amount');

    $query = $em->createNativeQuery($clientQuery, $rsm);
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

This will return an array with the given structure - *id, name, ncontracts, amount*  - which can be iterated in controller, twig template or whereever.